Calculating CRC-16 checksums for modbus correctly
I don't know much about generating G8501 fields.
The content of my dex document is as follows:
DXS*XYZ1234567*VA*V0/6*1
ST*001*0001
ID1*ABC98765*****12234
VA1*4550*2450
VA3*91*49
CA3*****2700*225*475*2000
CA4***250*0
EA2*EGS****0
EA3*********24*10
G85*DD0B
SE*10*0001
DXE*1*1

What needs to be calculated is as follows:
ST*001*0001
ID1*ABC98765*****12234
VA1*4550*2450
VA3*91*49
CA3*****2700*225*475*2000
CA4***250*0
EA2*EGS****0
EA3*********24*10

The value calculated according to CRC-16/MODBUS is: B25D
But the value calculated by some websites is: DD0B
Tell me the correct calculation method of G8501. It would be great if there is a code example.

You'll have to provide a lot more context. "G8501" alone does mean nothing.

another website is also returning B25D,  same as as the code posted in first answer (using '\n' instead of spaces ' ' in input data) - so "some websites" are not just returning CRC-16/MODBUS of the posted data (or different CRC, or different encoding, or different handling of lines, ...)

I was curious about it just recently too, what i got to figure out, that The discrepancy in the CRC values (likely B25D vs DD0B), could be due to different implementations or initial values used in the CRC calcs.
The CRC-16/MODBUS corresponds to the hexadecimal 0x8005(polynomial x^16 + x^15 + x^2 + 1) or in reverse order to 0xA001 and init value as 0xFFFF. I have tried to calculate it with some binary division like so:
public class CRC16Modbus {
public static int calculateCRC(byte[] data) {
    int crc = 0xFFFF; 
    for (byte b : data) {
        crc ^= b & 0xFF;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            if ((crc & 0x0001) != 0) {
                crc >>= 1;
                crc ^= 0xA001; 
            } else {
                crc >>= 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return crc & 0xFFFF; 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dataString = "ST0010001 ID1ABC98765*****12234 VA145502450 VA39149 CA3*****27002254752000 CA42500 EA2EGS0 EA3********24*10";
    byte[] data = dataString.getBytes();
    int crcValue = calculateCRC(data);
    System.out.printf("The CRC-16/MODBUS value is: %04X%n", crcValue);
}

}
Hope it will help, and you will use it as a reference

Thank you for your answer. I hope you are correct, but according to the answer provided by the website 'https://www.evadts.com/', the correct value should be '0xDD0B'. Unfortunately, I don't know what algorithm is used to obtain this value. of.

Just change int crc = 0xFFFF;  toint crc = 0x0000; , thank you
